# fetch data on dropdown change event from database to dataTables using ajax in Codeigniter 4

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

fetch data from database to datatables using ajax on dropdown change.

controller and model is working fine when use simple dropdown change event using ajax, but when try to fetch data to dataTables then show an error

> no data available

Controller:

```
   public function getStudents()
  {
      $model = new ModelAjax();
      $sessionid = $this->request->getVar('sessionid');
      $classid = $this->request->getVar('classid');
      $data =  $model->getStudents($sessionid,$classid);
      echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Model:

```
public function getStudents($sessionid,$classid)
    {
        $model = new ModelStudent();
        $array = ['sessionid' => $sessionid, 'classid' => $classid];
        $data = $model->select('tblstudent.studentname,tblstudent.fathername, tblstudent.rollno ,tblstudent.mobile1')
        ->join('tblenrollment','tblstudent.id = tblenrollment.studentid','left')
        ->where($array)
        ->findAll();
        return $data;
    }
```

Script:

```
$("#classid").change(function(){
        var sessionid = $("#sessionid").val();
        var classid = $(this).val();
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo site_url('Ajax/getStudents'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: function(d){
                d.sessionid = $("#sessionid").val();
                d.classid = $("#classid").val();
            }
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
              iDisplayLength: 15,
              buttons: [
                  'copyHtml5',
                  'excelHtml5',
                  'csvHtml5',
                  'pdfHtml5',
                  'pageLength'
              ],
              search: true
        
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally succeeded to do it:

```
$("#classid").change(function(){
        var sessionid = $("#sessionid").val();
        var classid = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo site_url('Ajax/getStudents'); ?>",
                method : "POST",             
                data : {sessionid: sessionid, classid: classid},
                async : true,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $('#example').DataTable({  
            destroy: true,    
            data : data, 
            columns: [
                     { data: 'studentname', title: "StudentName" },
                     { data: 'fathername', title: "Father Name" },
                     { data: 'rollno', title: "RollNo" },
                     { data: 'mobile1', title: "Mobile" }
                ],   
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                iDisplayLength: 15,
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'csvHtml5',
                    'pdfHtml5',
                    'pageLength'
                ],
                search: true
         });

                }
                                
            });
            return false;   
    });
```